# Unet predicting good shape but wrong class

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

[SOLVED] It was an error with matplotlib. The listed color map ('g', 'y', 'k') is rearanging the colors when there are only 2 of the 3 classes in the prediction array.

I want to detect hedgerows and forests, but sometimes, my model is predicting the good shapes but wrong classes.

The 3 classes are

1. (green) : forest
2. (yellow) : hedgerows
3. (black) : background

I'm using a Unet, I have 16k training samples and 20% for the validation.
I use the categorical crossentropy

Comment: what is the loss function you are using ?

Comment: categorical_crossentropy

Comment: try dice loss. and if you have a imbalanced set between two classes, use weighted dice loss. Have a look at this for some idea of dice loss .. https://forums.fast.ai/t/understanding-the-dice-coefficient/5838

Comment: if you are using keras, follow this, https://gist.github.com/wassname/7793e2058c5c9dacb5212c0ac0b18a8a . please look at the comments in the thread for further corrections

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] It was an error with matplotlib. The listed color map ('g', 'y', 'k') is rearanging colors when there are only 2 of the 3 classes in the prediction array.